# Delphi firemonkey android multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I tried to make multiworker thread for a android platform using delphi firemonkey using method from this [multithread](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25707)

it didn't work, is there any way to create worker thread like that?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Perhaps have a look at TTask http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_TTask_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the Parallel Programming Library, using Tasks that create threads here is a quick example

```
uses: System.Threading
var
    Mythreadtask : ITask;

procedure createthreads;
begin
    if Assigned(Mythreadtask) then
    begin
        if Mythreadtask.Status = TTaskStatus.Running then
        begin
        //If it is already running don't start it again
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
    Mythreadtask := TTask.Create (procedure ()
    var s : String //Create Thread var here
    begin
    //Do all logic in here
    //If you need to do any UI related modifications
     TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,procedure()
        begin 
            //Remeber to wrap them inside a Syncronize
        end);
    end);
// Ensure that objects hold no references to other objects so that they can be freed, to avoid memory leaks. 
end;
```

Add:

If you want to like in your comment want 5 worker threads you can make use of a array of tasks, this is extracted from the Parallel Programming Library Documentation

```
procedure createthreads;
var 
    tasks: array of ITask; //Declare your dynamic array of ITask 
    value: Integer; 
begin 
Setlength (tasks ,2); // Set the size of the Array (How many threads you want to use in your case this would be 5)
value := 0; 

//This the 1st thread because it is the thread located in position 1 of the array of tasks
tasks[0] := TTask.Create (procedure () 
begin 
    sleep (3000); // 3 seconds 
    TInterlocked.Add (value, 3000); 
 end); 
 tasks[0].Start;// until .Start is called your task is not executed
 // this starts the thread that is located in the position [0] of tasks 

 //And this is the 2nd thread 
 tasks[1] := TTask.Create (procedure () 
 begin 
     sleep (5000); // 5 seconds 
     TInterlocked.Add (value, 5000);
 end); 
 tasks[1].Start;// and the second thread is started 
 TTask.WaitForAll(tasks); {This will have the mainthread wait for all the 
                 {threads of tasks to finish before moving making sure that when the
                 showmessage All done is displayed all the threads are done} 
 ShowMessage ('All done: ' + value.ToString); 
 end;
```

Comment: this is what i looking for, thanks @peter-john jansen, antoher question so for example i need 5 different worker thread i just create 5 procedure createthreads; for example procedure createthreads1; procedure createthreads2; and so on..?

Comment: Create a Array of Tasks and then you can start and stop them easily, that link I shared in my comment shows how to create a array of tasks and use them

Comment: Hi @SuperBug if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Its probably SO's fault that he forgot to mark this as an answer.